# How can I display my data in horizontal format in asp.net C# through DataList/RepeaterConrol or Gridview from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, datalist, asprepeater

I want bind data from database in Horizontal format data is in datatbase e.g

EMPLOYEES FROM CLIENT SIDE

Record      ACompany   BCompany CComapany  DCompany
Count          10         20        30       40

Comment: can you please format the output and share it for better clarity of the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can use 'PIVOT' function in Sql server and get data in horizontal format from database directly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ListView instead of Gridview which will give you more flexibility in showing the data.

If required you can use Repeater control inside Listview too.